# SpecFlow, Webdriver and Mocks - is it possible?

Tags: asp.net, mocking, bdd, webdriver, specflow

The question in short is that we are stumbling upon BDD definitions that more or less require different states - which leads to the necessity for a mock of sorts for ASP.NET/MVC - I know of none, which is why I ask here

Details:
We are developing a project in ASP.NET (MVC3/Razor engine) and are using SpecFlow to drive our development.

We quite often stumble into situations where we need the webpage under test to perform in a certain manner so that we can verify the behavior, i.e:

```
Scenario: Should render alternatively when backend system is down
    Given that the backend system is down
    And there are no channels for the page to display
    When I inspect the webpage under test
    Then the page renderes an alternative html indicating that there is a problem
```

For a unit test, this is less of an issue - run mock on the controller bit, and verify that it delivers the correct results, however, for a SpecFlow test, this is more or less requiring alternate configurations.

So it is possible at all, or - are there some known software patterns for developing webpages using BDD that I've missed?

Comment: Hi, did you ever get an acceptable answer to this? Do you if Deleporter is a realistic option?

Answer (score 2):

Even when using SpecFlow, you can still use a mocking framework. What I would do is use the `[BeforeScenario]` attribute to set up the mocks for the test e.g.

```
[BeforeScenario]
public void BeforeShouldRenderAlternatively()
{
   // Do mock setups.
}
```

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943625/feature-scoped-step-definitions-with-specflow) might come in handy for you also.

Comment: Yes, I know about this, but I am guessing the real question is: what pattern do you follow in order to put an ASP.NET web aplication in a known state? Mocking does not seem to apply - are there other, better patterns to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what patterns you may have heard of, but do you mean putting the database in a known state for a test?

Comment: Well, there is no database. We have a service layer that is the backbone of the ASP.Net pages. The reason why I asked for a pattern is simply because I am banging my head against the wall, and I am certain that I am not the only one to ever have wanted to verify a behavior under a known state. I can do so in Unit tests, however, BDD is one step over that, and right now, it is screaming for mocks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Deleporter](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/09/deleporter-cross-process-code-injection-for-aspnet/)

> Deleporter is a little .NET library that teleports arbitrary delegates into an ASP.NET application in some other process (e.g., hosted in IIS) and runs them there.
>
> It lets you delve into a remote ASP.NET application’s internals without any special cooperation from the remote app, and then you can do any of the following:
>
> - **Cross-process mocking**, by combining it with any mocking tool. For example, you could inject a temporary mock database or simulate the passing of time (e.g., if your integration tests want to specify what happens after 30 days or whatever)
> - **Test different configurations**, by writing to static properties in the remote ASP.NET appdomain or using the ConfigurationManager API to edit its  entries.
> - **Run teardown or cleanup logic** such as flushing caches. For example,  recently I needed to restore a SQL database to a known state after each test in the suite. The trouble was that ASP.NET connection pool was still holding open connections on the old database, causing connection errors. I resolved this easily by using Deleporter to issue a SqlConnection.ClearAllPools() command in the remote appdomain – the ASP.NET app under test didn’t need to know anything about it.

Comment: To save others trouble, as of the date of this comment, Deleporter was last updated over a decade ago, in 2010.