# SpecFlow Teardown Opens and Closes Multiple Blank Browsers

Tags: selenium, bdd, specflow

I am in the process of converting a bunch of selenium test cases over to SpecFlow. Everything is working well but what is driving me crazy is that I am using an after scenario to do a driver.quit. When that executes, I have roughly 4-6 browsers opening and closing. In looking at the task manager, it is killing all of the chromedriver.exe (a second one is opened somewhere) and chrome.exe processes successfully which is great. If I run the same test in selenium, I just have one browser and it closes. When SpecFlow runs now, it basically adds 10-20 seconds onto my runs as it opens and closes browsers.

If I change my browser to Firefox I get the same thing. One browser opens and at completion, several blank firefox browsers open and close.

Any ideas what could be causing this behavior? I have searched all over and no one seems to have ever experienced this but me.

Appreciate the help.

Here is teardown code. I have it in a basetestobject class and it is inherited by the specflow classes. I have tried removing the [TestCleanup] but the same result applies.

BaseTestObject.cs

```
    public class BaseTestObject
     {
    private IWebDriver seleniumDriver;
    private IDriver testDriver;

    [TestInitialize]
    public virtual void Setup()
    {
        TestDriver.goToUrl(ConfigProperties.StartUrl);
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void ScenarioTearDown()
    {
     TestDriver.Quit();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void CleanUp()
    {
        TestDriver.Quit();

    }


    public IWebDriver SeleniumDriver
    {
        get
        {
            if (seleniumDriver == null)
            {
                seleniumDriver = GetDriver();
            }
            return seleniumDriver;
        }
    }

    public IDriver TestDriver
    {
        get
        {
            if (testDriver == null)
            {
                testDriver = new UiDriver(SeleniumDriver);
            }
            return testDriver;
        }
    }


    public CurrentPageObjectScope On
    {
        get
        {
            return new CurrentPageObjectScope(TestDriver);
        }
    }

    public static String GetTimestamp()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssfff");
    }

    public static String GetTimestamp2()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy");
    }

    private IWebDriver GetDriver()
    {
        switch (ConfigProperties.Browser.ToLower())
        {
            case "firefox":
                return new FirefoxDriver();
            case "chrome":


                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                ChromeDriverService service =                ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"../Chrome/");
                service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
                service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
                options.AddArguments("test-type");
                options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
                return new ChromeDriver(service, options);



            case "ie":
            case "internetexplorer":

                return new InternetExplorerDriver(@"../IE/");


            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Unknown browser string in Config properties " + ConfigProperties.Browser);
        }


    }
```

Edit 9.15.14

resolved by adding the below in my baseTestObject. Thanks for the help.

```
    [AfterScenario]
    public void CleanUp()
    {
        if (seleniumDriver != null)
        {
            SeleniumDriver.Dispose();
            seleniumDriver = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I too have found opening/closing the browser to be costly in terms of time. In the project I'm working on we don't kill the browser, we re-use it e.g. Navigate to a different start point once a scenario has completed or do a complete refresh.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Nice alternative. It is just strange that I do not see this behaviour when I run the basic google test. I am thinking it is  my framework but regular selenium tests close immediately. I actually disabled the afterscenario so right now I manually close it. If I run an entire suite, I enable the afterscenario and let it close it. Not a great workaround.

Comment: Can you include your AfterScenario code in the question? Also include your BeforeScenario hook code if you are using that too.

Comment: added to the initial post. Thanks for the help Ben.

Comment: Have you also got the code for "TestDriver.Quit();" is that something you've written? As has been mentioned in Sam's suggested answer, you shouldn't need TestCleanup if you are closing the browser after every scenario.

Comment: Just to let you guys know I played with this a bit more today!! I created a new basetestobject class and added my teardown in it. I then updated a steps scenario to inherit the new basetestobject class. When I ran the test, I had one browser and it closed immediately the way it should. I then modified a different step class and changed the inheritance on it to also point to the new basetestobject class. I then reran the same test case as before. This time I had a second browser open and then close. Why is the inheritance of a class causing this to invoke the teardown more than once???

Comment: Ben - I was looking at other posts and ran across one you answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642514/global-beforescenario-afterscenario-steps-in-specflow - That is the exact scenario I am using except my driver info is in there as I posted in my initial post. I am racking my brain on this lol.

Comment: Yep, your problem sounds odd. You didn't answer my question "Have you also got the code for "TestDriver.Quit();" is that something you've written?"

Comment: here is the only code I could find in the project.         public void Quit()
        {
            SeleniumDriver.Quit();
        }

Answer (score 1):

We ended up doing what's described in [this post](http://brantleytec.blogspot.com/2014/06/webdriver-context.html).  It allows browser reuse (if you want) between scenarios and closes everything only "AfterFeature" (not after scenario run).

Comment: The link is dead now.

Comment: @BenPower it seems to be working fine for me. http://brantleytec.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/webdriver-context.html

Comment: @Sirk That's strange, I still can't view it, I just get an icon with 2 gears spinning. It might be a regional issue perhaps?