# Multiple browser instance launch when i execute my test

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, c#-4.0, specflow

I an new in specflow i am implementing framework. When i create one feature file with multiple scenario and execute my test than it open one browser instance and run successful when i add one more feature file with multiple scenario and execute my test than it launch multiple browser instance one instance for each scenario can anyone help me out what's wrong in my code

```
Start.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace Orange_HRM
{
    class Start : SeleniumDriver
    {

      [BeforeScenarioBlock]
        public void Setup()
        {
            Intitialize();
            WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(BaseAddress);
        } 

        [AfterScenarioBlock]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}

SeleniumDriver.cs

using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Orange_HRM
{
    class SeleniumDriver
    {

        public static IWebDriver WebDriver;


        public static string BaseAddress
        {
            get { return Constants.Url; }
        }

        public static void Intitialize()
        {
            WebDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            WebDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            TurnOnWait();
        }

        public static void Navigate()
        {
            WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(BaseAddress);
        }

        public static void Close()
        {
            WebDriver.Close();
        }

        public static void Quit()
        {
            WebDriver.Quit();
        }

        private static void TurnOnWait()
        {
            WebDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            WebDriver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: please where is your main() method or object creation for class Orange_HRM and what is purpose of putting using System.Threading.Tasks namespace

Comment: refere post <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028926/run-selenium-tests-in-multiple-browsers-one-after-another-from-c-sharp-nunit> and post <https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5755/what-is-the-best-way-to-have-a-specflow-project-run-across-multiple-browsers> and post <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467957/specflow-teardown-opens-and-closes-multiple-blank-browsers>

Answer (score 0):

You are using SpecFlow of techtalk.
Concept name is Hooks.
to perform automatic logic operations at specific timings.So, hooks are event bindings.
running tests in multiple threads with SpecFlow+ Runner.

So, you can put orders,

```
class Start : SeleniumDriver
{
[BeforeScenario(Order = 0)]
public void Setup()
        {
            Intitialize();
            WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(BaseAddress);
        } 

[BeforeScenario(Order = 1)]
public void TearDown()
        {
            Close();
        }
}
```

i like to suggest you dont use them, Bindings Class without Hooks.
i.e. [BeforeTestRun] [AfterTestRun] use them instead.

```
[AfterScenario]
public void CleanUp()
{
    if (seleniumDriver != null)
    {
        SeleniumDriver.Dispose();
        seleniumDriver = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ashish 
I follow the approach which you provide but still same multiple browser instance launch when i execute my test.

Comment: I think @Navarasu answer should have to work have you tried that.

Comment: Hi Ashish
I tried Navarasu solution but its giving me an error, I have mention the error in my comment.
Please suggest any other solution.
Thanks

Comment: is there any [Parallelizable] public class

Comment: We have annotation Parallelizable in nunit but i didn't create Parallelizable class in this test

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise and close the driver at Test Run level instead of scenario level. And maintain the url navigation alone at Scenario level. So that the driver will be initiated before test starts and quit after the test completes. Also the page will get refreshed before each scenario run.

```
namespace Orange_HRM
{
    class Start : SeleniumDriver
    {

      [BeforeTestRun]
        public static void Setup()
        {
            Intitialize();
        } 

        [AfterTestRun]
        public static void TearDown()
        {
            Quit();
        }

        [AfterScenarioBlock]
        public void navigateToUrl()
        {
            WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(BaseAddress);
        } 
    }
}
```

Also you have used WebDriver.Close() instead WebDriver.Quit(). If we use WebDriver.Close() for the main window, then session will be terminated. Then if we try to access the same webdriver object again, it will throw No such session error.

WebDriver.Close() is meant for closing child window if we are working with mulitple windows. So to close main window, we have to use WebDriver.Quit() directly.

Comment: Hi Navarasu,
 
I follow the same approach which you provide and now it's giving me an error, Test doesn't start just display an error. 

TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Oops typo. I misplaced AfterScenarioBlock and AfterTestRun hooks. I edited above code. Can you check now with changed code?

Comment: Hi Navarasu, I tried with updated code but now its giving me an error while execute the test

Comment: I am getting following error 
NUnit3TestExecutor converted 6 of 6 NUnit test cases
TearDown failed for test fixture CompleteAutomation.Feature.TestOrangeHRMLoginFunctionalityFeature
TechTalk.SpecFlow.BindingException : The binding methods for before/after feature and before/after test run events must be static! CompleteAutomation:Orange_HRM.Hooks.Setup()
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I also change the Befor and after mehod to static and now i am getting the following error 
System.ArgumentExceptiion: The SearchContext of the locator object cannot be null
Parameter name: locator
Please suggest any other solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you need to explore more about basics <https://ralucasuditu-softwaretesting.blogspot.com/2016/04/specflow-using-hooks-in-your-tests.html>

Comment: Looks like your using PageFactory and the page factory get initiated before Initialiaze call. Check which line is calling it before calling Initialize method in debug mode. Add the test class and page object class to the quesion.