# How to setup a selenium solution from scratch

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, config, specflow

I'm in the process of creating a new Selenium Solution from scratch and have come across an error which I'm trying to resolve, if someone could kindly assist.

Firstly I have a generic app.config using the MsTest framework...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
  </configSections>
  <specFlow>
    <unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />
  </specFlow>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Browser" value="Chrome" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The purpose of creating an app.config file was so I could manipulate the appSettings and pass any value against the key value 'Browser'.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;  
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome; 
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;     
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace Automation
{
    [Binding]
    [TestFixture]
    public class GoogleTests_Chrome
    {
        private IWebDriver _driver;

        [TestFixtureSetUp]
        public void FixtureSetup()
        {
            switch (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Browser"])
            {
                case "Chrome":
                    _driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
                    _driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
                    _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                    break;
                case "Firefox":
                    _driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
                    _driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
                    _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                    break;
                case "IE":
                    _driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                    _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
                    _driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
                    _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Defaulting to Firefox");
                    _driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
                    _driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
                    _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                    break;
            }
        }

        [Given("I have navigated to (.*) in my web browser")]
        public void TestSetUp(string url)
        {
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        }

        [Then("I want to verify that the page has loaded successfully")]
        public void GooglePageTitle()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("Google", _driver.Title);
        }

        [TestFixtureTearDown]
        public void FixtureTearDown()
        {
            if (_driver != null) _driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

At this stage I have created a simple specFlow feature file shown below to execute the following steps.

```
Feature: AutomationFeature

@mytag
Scenario: Navigate to the Google homepage
    Given I have navigated to http://www.google.com in my web browser
    Then I want to verify that the page has loaded successfully
```

Unfortunately whenever I run the test I keep getting the following error '{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}'. I've noticed that the _driver value is returning as null. Any ideas?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Where do you call FixtureSetup method ? Why not put break point on this method and see if it is called.If the method is called check why it is not going in any of the cases.

I don't see your method with [Test] attribute in the code which you post.

Edit:

```
[TestFixture]
class GoogleTestsChrome
{
    [Test]
    public void GoogleTest()
    {
         try
         {
              FixtureSetup();

              _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
              Assert.AreEqual("Google", _driver.Title);
         }
         finally
         {
              _driver.Quit();
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, The way the I'm calling 'FixtureSetup' is with the use of [TestFixtureSetUp], from my understanding this is a attribute that is used to call any method before any tests are run. I have attempted to place a breakpoint on the 'FixtureSetup' method but it doesn't seem to be executed . It's being ignored completely during debug. I did add the [Test] attribute into the code but that didn't get resolve the issue as of yet

Answer (score 0):

your issue is that you are mixing specflow and normal unit tests.

When using specflow it **generates** the unit tests for you so you don't need to use any unit test attributes in your steps.

Try removing all of the unit test infrastructure from your binding class and use the specflow defined attributes to do the same things, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;  
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome; 
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;     
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace Automation
{
    [Binding]    
    public class GoogleTests_Chrome
    {
        private IWebDriver _driver;

        [BeforeScenario]
        public void FixtureSetup()
        {
            switch (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Browser"])
            {
                case "Chrome":
                    _driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
                    _driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
                    _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                    break;
                case "Firefox":
                    _driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
                    _driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
                    _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                    break;
                case "IE":
                    _driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                    _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
                    _driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
                    _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Defaulting to Firefox");
                    _driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
                    _driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
                    _driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                    break;
            }
        }

        [Given("I have navigated to (.*) in my web browser")]
        public void TestSetUp(string url)
        {
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        }

        [Then("I want to verify that the page has loaded successfully")]
        public void GooglePageTitle()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("Google", _driver.Title);
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void FixtureTearDown()
        {
            if (_driver != null) _driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

you also have an issue that you have parametereized this method:

```
[Given("I have navigated to (.*) in my web browser")]
public void TestSetUp(string url)
```

but not this one:

```
[Then("I want to verify that the page has loaded successfully")]
public void GooglePageTitle()
```

which means that unless you pass a google url into the TestSetup method then your `Then` step is going to fail.  You should pass in the title you want to check in your `Then` step, like this

```
[Then("The page should have loaded successfully and the title should be '(.*)'")]
public void ValidatePageHasLoadedSuccessfully(string title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixture setup doesn't work with SpecFlow.  If you're just trying to create a browser, I would suggest using a context file as described in [this blog post](http://brantleytec.blogspot.com/2014/06/webdriver-context.html). Otherwise, you'll need to define the setup and teardown as [BeforeScenario("mytag")] or [AfterScenario("mytag")].  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943625/feature-scoped-step-definitions-with-specflow) for something similar.